# How to use group by, count, and where in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table, described like so:
**Table1**

```
id (int), 
link (varchar512),
text (varchar80),
status (varchar10),
created (timestamp),
updated (timestamp),
user (varchar)
```

What I need to do is get the `total count` of rows per user between two timestamps.

So, for example, let's say I want to get the total number of rows for users in the database. That is just a simple

```
 SELECT user, COUNT(*) FROM table_name GROUP BY user;
```

If I want to get all the rows, for say October, I can do:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE created > "2016-10-01 00:00:00" and created < "2016-11-31 23:59:59"
```

My problem, is I cannot combine the two. I try, and I get syntax errors. I *think* that I need to run the where query, and then do a count based on that, but I'm not sure how do to that.

Comment: Excuse me, but what did you try? Have you ever looked at the mysql documentation? This is a simple combination of where and group by. No magic involved here.

Comment: Excused?

Also, the mysql documentation is downright byzantine. and I didn't say anything about magic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps.

```
SELECT user, count(*) 
FROM table_name
WHERE created > "2016-10-01 00:00:00" and created < "2016-11-31 23:59:59"
GROUP BY user;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user, COUNT(*) 
FROM table_name 
WHERE created >= '2016-10-01' 
  and created < '2016-12-01'
GROUP BY user;
```

BTW there is no date `2016-11-31` since November has only 30 days.